# Checkbox in DataGridView does not change its value after checking it

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I have checkboxes in one of my columns in DataGridView.

And now I have a problem: When I click **once** on Checkbox it changes but only visualy, in code its value is still set to false. But if I click on Checkbox and then anywhere else on my datagridview (or change its value manually in code on true) it changes its value on true.

How can I force my checkbox to change value after one click? (it's annoying that checking checkbox actually does not check it).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The changes are applied when the control loses the focus. Are you using autogenerated columns or explicitly created ones? It is the same behavior as when editing text field: the underlying object will not change on each typed letter, it will change at the end, when the focus is changed. This is by design.

Comment: The column is autogenerated.
So is there any event that will work in this situation?

Comment: `CellContentClick` if you want to handle it explicitly

Comment: I've upvoted you back to zero. I see nothing wrong with your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Changes to underlying data source are applied when the controls lose the focus.
You can handle it explicitly in [`CellContentClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontentclick.aspx) event.

Please read the linked documentation thoroughly, as it describes similar scenarios, and discusses different type of grid cells.

Found also [this](http://codingeverything.blogspot.com/2013/01/firing-datagridview-cellvaluechanged.html). Exactly the same problem.

Comment: I got the same issue. I just add
 Private Sub EndEditMode(sender As System.Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dgv.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged
             If dgv.IsCurrentCellDirty Then
            dgv.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
        End If
    End Sub ``
And it works...

Answer (score 2):

Lets assume like you have a form with name **Form1**

A DataGridView in it name **dgv**

A CheckBoxColumn in it with ColumnIndex = **5**

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    dgv.CellContentClick += dgv_CellContentClick;
}
```

Commit the change for datagrid within the event for that specific column

```
private void dgv_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 5) dgv.EndEdit();
}
```